# this is really hard for me, and what should i do?

Tags: c++

my question is in c++.how to compare two different length string. for example `string a = "ap"` `string b = "apple"`. so the final match should be 1, or consider another example, let's say `string a = "123"` `string b = "123123123"`, the final match should be 3. so what i'm think is i try to let `a[i]= b[i]` but it's just comparing only 1 charcater. how to compare a muliple length string.

```
int getMatchCount(string a, string b)
{
    int match = 0;

    if (a.length() == 0 or b.length() == 0 )
    {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++)
    {

        if( string.compare(a, b) )
        {
            match = match +1;
        }
    }
    return match;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find and maybe http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

Comment: You may want to read about [regular expressions in c++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). But beforehand you may want to take the [tour] again, learn [ask] and then come back and ask a new question.

Comment: What sould be
a = 'abc', b = '123 abc 456'
a = 'abc', b = 'abc something else abc again'
? Its not clear what you want to do...

Comment: `string.compare(a, b)` is not C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using `std::string::find`

```
#include <iostream>

int getMatchCount(std::string a, std::string b)
{
    int match = 0;
    std::size_t pos = 0;

    while ((pos = b.find(a, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
        ++pos;
        ++match;
    }

    return match;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << getMatchCount("is", "isis");
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit**
I use `std::size_t` since I want to compare it with `std::string::npos`. An int is not guaranteed to be big enough to be able to do that. `std::size_t` is also unsigned, which makes it a good choice to represent indexes.

If we break down the loop it runs `b.find(a, pos)` which will find the first occurance of the substring `a` in string `b`. The return value will be either the index of where the substring starts if a match is found or `std::string::npos` if it's not found.

The first time the loops run `pos` is `0` so we start from the beginning of string b when we search. We then store the returned value in `pos`. (In our example that will be `0` again for the first match)

If the returned value was not `std::string::npos` we found a match, so we increase `match`. For the next iteration of the loop we want to start the search after the last match, so we increment `pos` by one. (In our example, we increment it to 1, and search for the substring starting at index 1 and onward)

Comment: and why we need to use std::size_t pos = 0? can you explian that while loop for me?

Comment: @bro Added some explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a naive, but viable solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::string first = "hello";
    std::string second = "hello_world";
    int match = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < std::min(first.length(), second.length()); ++i) {
        if(first.at(i) == second.at(i)) {
            match++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout << match << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Because it was requested:

The `#include <algorithm>` was there for the `std::min()` function in order to avoid accessing an invalid memory address.  That is, it prevents the `for` loop from accessing any `string` index greater than `string.length()`, which would result in undefined behaviour ...or back when I was learning C++, a `segmentation fault`.

In this case it has been replaced with some logic and the short-hand ternary operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string first = "hello";
    string second = "hello_world";
    int match = 0;
    size_t lowest = first.length() <= second.length() ? first.length() : second.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < lowest; ++i) {
        if(first.at(i) == second.at(i)) {
            match++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << match << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants, it will compair character by character.

Comment: If the op adds an inner loop the problem is solved, the solution shows a simple, intuitive way to solve the problem.

Comment: sorry I haven't learnt #include<algorithm>, can u explain my question with a more simple way, and I hope u can delete those std:: and instead using namespace std; ty

Comment: @bro - namespace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice